# Angular Material with other CSS Framework

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm about to start my first Angular project, and I'm thinking about using Angular Material.

It has a lot of components which is what i'm looking for but it seems to me that it does not have a grid system nor any utility classes.

Should I use for example Bootstrap or any other css framework along with Angular Material or simply add my own css? What's the common practice?

Having to add classes for padding, margin and so on is a waste of time so I'd be inclined to also use Bootstrap which already has all these kind of classes.

My only fear is that having both Angular Material and Bootstrap  would increase the bundle significantly.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following for my project

1. For grid, checkout this https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/.
2. For
   angular wrapper of bootstrap you can check
   https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation#getting-started
3. You may also want to check
   https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/setup this has UI
   components as well as their own spacing and grid setup
   https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/primeflex/spacing

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll give a chance to primeng since it has a lot of components and a grid system as well.